# Помогите решить задачу по топологии. Аксиомы счетности

Tags: математика

> Докажите, что факторпространство X/R пространства X, удовлетворяющего второй аксиоме счетности, удовлетворяет второй аксиоме счетности в том и только том случае, если оно удовлетворяет первой аксиоме счетности.

Слева на право понятно как доказать. Не понятно как справа на лево доказывается.

Comment: у вас уже не первый вопрос на такие темы, я бы вам посоветовал бы все таки другой ресурс - http://mathhelpplanet.com/index.php